# Phishing domain converting text due to special character?

Tags: phishing, url

**Warning:** The following links are phishing links, please do not sign in to them.

Today, a friend of mine came across the link `hxxp://steạmcommunlty(dot)com/tradeoffer/new/`. It's a phishing link, but I have no idea how it works. Notice the a in steam is a special character? When you go to that link and copy and paste it, it somehow converts to `xn--stemcommunlty-kf2g(dot)com`

How is it doing that? Is it something to do with the `ạ` converting into something else making it a completely different URL?

Comment: Compare https://www.аррӏе.com with https://www.apple.com. It's just unicode which has characters that look identical to regular ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser is doing this [to follow the standard regarding hostnames containing non-ASCII characters](https://www.w3.org/International/wiki/IRIStatus):

> Non-ASCII domain names ("IDNA") rely on a special transfer encoding
>   ("[Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)") to allow non-ASCII domain values inside the ASCII-only
>   DNS nameserver hierarchy. Punycode encodes a domain name such as
>   "faß.de" using special markup that looks like so: "xn--fa-hia.de"

**This is done for all domains containing such characters**, and has nothing to do with domain being phishing.

PS. Your "steạmcommunlty" domain name also uses lowercase L instead of I in the word "community".